# SELECT specific information

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My tables are structured like this (there are more values in the tables but I only wrote the ones relevant to this):

```
Department(dep_id, dep_name)  
Employee(dep_id)
```

I need to display dep_name and the number of employees in every department, except once specific department (let's call it DepX) and only the departments with more than one employee.
I tried multiple methods to solve this but none of them worked.
Some methods I tried:

```
SELECT department.dep_name, COUNT(employee.dep_id) AS NumberOfEmployees FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON employee.dep_id=department.dep_id
WHERE dep_name<>'DepX'
GROUP BY dep_id
HAVING COUNT(employee.dep_id) > 1;

SELECT dep_name FROM department
WHERE dep_name <>'DepX'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee
WHERE COUNT(*) > 1
GROUP BY dep_id;
```

I can't figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `none of them worked`?  An error message?  No results?  Wrong results?  Please give clear examples; such as the data you are using, the results you expected, and the results you actually got.

Comment: what is the problem with your first method, could you please post the error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example does now work because you're including dep_name in your results without an aggregation but not grouping on it.

You can either use the department name in your grouping instead of the ID:

```
SELECT department.dep_name, COUNT(employee.dep_id) AS NumberOfEmployees FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON employee.dep_id=department.dep_id
WHERE dep_name<>'DepX'
GROUP BY department.dep_name
HAVING COUNT(employee.dep_id) > 1;
```

or do the `COUNT` in a subquery:

```
SELECT department.dep_name, 
       e.NumberOfEmployees 
FROM department
INNER JOIN (SELECT dep_id, 
                   COUNT(*) NumberOfEmployees 
            FROM employee
            GROUP BY dept_id
            HAVING COUNT(dept_id) > 1    
           ) e
ON department.dep_id = e.dep_id
WHERE dep_name<>'DepX'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT department.dep_name, COUNT(employee.dep_id) AS NumberOfEmployees FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON employee.dep_id=department.dep_id
WHERE department.dep_name not in('DepX')
GROUP BY department.dep_name
HAVING COUNT(employee.dep_id) > 1;
```

**update your table alias per your need**

Comment: Won't that return
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'department.dep_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause?

Answer (score 0):

TEST this. This query help you return not only dept_name, it can return all fields from Department if you want:

```
SELECT d.*, A.numOfEmployees
FROM Department d,
     (
    SELECT e.dep_id, COUNT(*) numOfEmployees
    FROM Employee e
    GROUP BY e.dep_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) A
WHERE d.dep_id = A.dep_id
AND d.dep_name != 'DepX'
```